# Seamless Tilemap Rendering C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, shader

I am attempting to create a seamless 2D tilemap renderer in C++. The goal is to have little to no loading screens as the player progresses from each map to the other.

For example:
[image: Each square is a zone/tilemap; the red square is the viewable area]
Each square in the above picture is a zone / tilemap; the red square is the viewable camera. In this example, each zone is 256x256 and stored inside an `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` - lets also say the camera has a viewable area of 60x60 (of 32x32 tiles)

My issues currently are how to decide:

1. What tiles to display from each given zone.
2. How to calculate the offset to draw said tiles at.

Slightly related, if someone is interested in creating this technology I am more than willing to pay for it :)

I am a software engineer by trade, however graphics are hardly my strong suit. The end goal is to develop an old school RPG using OpenGL 3.2 with shader support.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Do it minecraft style - 'load' chunks when the player gets sufficiently close to them. 'unload' them when he gets sufficiently far away, and render all loaded chunks. Then the user will never see a gap instead of the map ^^

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Interesting thought Patashu, however what really confuses me is how to display all the zone data. Lets say you have four std::vector< std::vector<int> > - each one has 256x256 tiles. You know which zones are related to each other, however deciding what data should be rendered and where is what I am unfortunately getting confused on.

Comment: It might also be possible that you have a discrete set of tiles, in which case, you'll only be loading this discrete set of tiles into the memory and referencing these. Then, you don't exactly need to front-load any other texture, just blit these discrete tiles onto the screen. My opinion, but, in that case, you'd perhaps also not want to engage in premature optimization. Simply create a renderer that blits the stuff that you want at run-time and see if its getting you good enough frame-rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow this brings me back..  Ok here's how I implemented that back in the day (using directdraw 7 but really the graphics engine behind this is irrelevant). This code only draws what the camera can see at any given point (which is really the only thing you should be drawing). Also keep in mind, this code is OLD and around when I first started learning how to develop. It's not gonna be very pretty:

```
// set original render location to x = 0, y = 0, width = tileWidth, height = tileHeight
// this is the top left corner of the screen
RECT renderLoc = { 0, 0, g_MapData.m_TileSize, g_MapData.m_TileSize }; 

// the first column of visible tiles is given by the x coordinate divided 
// by the tilesize and first visible row is given by the y coordinate/tileWidth
int xStartCol = g_MapData.m_xCamera / g_MapData.m_TileSize;
int yStartRow = g_MapData.m_yCamera / g_MapData.m_TileSize;

// calculate the number of tiles in the current resolution that are visible
int xVisibleTiles = (dd7.m_ScreenWidth/g_MapData.m_TileSize);
int yVisibleTiles = (dd7.m_ScreenHeight/g_MapData.m_TileSize);

// if the tilesize is not divisible by the screensize then the 
// number of visible tiles will not calculate correctly. It will 
// be a float and since this is truncated, it will contain a row or 
// column less than what it requires. This code compensates for that
// by just adding one more row to round up instead of down.
if (dd7.m_ScreenWidth%g_MapData.m_TileSize) { xVisibleTiles++; }

if (dd7.m_ScreenHeight%g_MapData.m_TileSize) { yVisibleTiles++; }

// now just add the size in tiles of the visible screen to get the end
int xEndCol = xStartCol + xVisibleTiles;
int yEndRow = yStartRow + yVisibleTiles;

// Visible tiles referring to the tiles that can be displayed across and 
//down on the screen (this depends on the resolution set)

// now check if the camera coordinates are divisible by the tile size
int x, y, l; // variables for loops and checks

x = g_MapData.m_xCamera % g_MapData.m_TileSize;
y = g_MapData.m_yCamera % g_MapData.m_TileSize;

if (!x)
{
    // remove a column to draw since it divided perfectly. We originally    
    //added one to the visible rows and columns
xEndCol--;
}
else 
{
// need to move renderLoc RECT. Since there could be half a column    
//exposed which forces us to draw that portion. we only want to draw what 
//is currently on the viewable screen to save memory.
renderLoc.left -= x;
renderLoc.right -= x;
}

// now do the same for rows
if (!y)
{
yEndRow--;
else 
{
renderLoc.top -= y;
renderLoc.bottom -= y;
}

// now check to make sure we're not exceeding map size
if (xEndCol > g_MapData.m_xMaxTiles) { xEndCol = g_MapData.m_xMaxTiles; }
if (yEndRow > g_MapData.m_yMaxTiles) { yEndRow = g_MapData.m_yMaxTiles; }

// Now Draw!
// for each layer 
for ( l = 0; l < g_MapData.m_Layers; l++) {
// draw the rows
for ( x = xStartCol; x <= xEndCol; x++) {
    // column by column
    for ( y = yStartRow; y <= yEndRow; y++) {               
    tileToRender = g_MapData.m_Tiles[x][y][l]; 
// Finish your drawing..
```

Comment: I should clarify as well, this eliminates the need for you to split things up into many different small maps (unless your goal is to avoid having a large map file, then really all your doing is paging memory in from disk when it's needed.. if that's from one file or many is really irrelevent

Comment: I was originally aiming at having numerous small maps (perhaps say 500x500). I am actually not familiar with paging memory and unsure how safe that would be since I am targeting mobile devices as well. Do you suppose one large file plus a std::deque would work correctly- the data would be pushed/popped from either end as it is paged from disk?

Comment: Since your goal is to have one large contiguous world, it doesn't really make sense for you to split things into a bunch of other small map files. It seems you're only creating problems for yourself. If your map is absolutely enormous, you will definitely need to look at paging out to disk and paging in, but that can be expensive and can hurt performance especially on mobile devices. I recommend you create just one large map and keep that map in memory

Comment: You're likely correct Jared, thank you for all the advice! I suspect that a map that has layers compressed using ZRLE (or something similar) would make even large maps manageable if I paired it with a quadtree or something similar.